# How to add jquery selections together without sorting in DOM order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery element, I'd like to search all of it's next siblings looking for a possible match and if that fails search all the previous ones.

I would have thought I could do something like:

```
myDiv.nextAll("li").add(myDiv.prevAll("li")).each(function()
{
     if (match) { return this; }
}
```

However, this does not work. When I call jquery Add it seems to sort the collection in the order they appear in the DOM meaning that I always go back to the first matching element. I can't think of a simple way to fix this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that most jQuery operations put the DOM elements into DOM sorted order.  That's the way jQuery works and it does that because it's usually very useful and important.

In your case, however, I think it means you will have to do two separate searches so things are searched in the right order.  If the first search fails to find a result, then carry out the second one:

```
function fn() {
    if (match) {return this;}
}

var results = myDiv.nextAll("li").each(fn);
if (!results.length) {
    results = myDiv.prevAll("li").each(fn);
}
```

The only other solution I can think of would be to create your own jQuery object with unsorted elements.  You would need to do a manual manipulation of the jQuery DOM element array rather than using built-in methods like `.add()` that automatically sort things.  In this particular case, that wouldn't be less code than what we have above and would also not be a more efficient way of solving the problem because you'd get all DOM elements even when you don't need the `prevAll()` set.

Per your comment, if you want the prevAll() items sorted in DOM order, you would have to do something like this:

```
function fn() {
    if (match) {return this;}
}

var results = myDiv.nextAll("li").each(fn);
if (!results.length) {
    results = $().add(myDiv.prevAll("li")).each(fn);
}
```

The extra `.add()` will cause jQuery to sort the `.prevAll()` results into DOM order.

Comment: +1 for doing the refactoring I was thinking about instead of what I actually answered.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not 100% clear here. If it fails to find a match in the next elements I would like it to start at the top of the previous ones. prevAll does not actually sort in DOM order and so this will go to the previous one.

Comment: @Porco - I added an additional option to my answer that sorts the `prevAll()` results in DOM order.

Comment: Very nice, I actually need to add myDiv back in anyway (so that if nothing previous matches we stay on original element).